# .vue files without jsx

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, jsx

Is there a way to have `.vue` files for each component, but without that pseudo-javascript language jsx ?

I like the idea of having all the components and templates in separate files, but that stupid "language" is freaking me out.

Comment: explore vue world and docs before asking questions here

Comment: JSX is a React thing; Vue has its own template system.  It's possible to use JSX in Vue, but you have to go out of your way to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ///// example.vue
<temlate>
    // Write Html codes .....
</temlate>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    // Write isolate style
</style>

<script>
////    Example javascript code
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import PageBreadcrumb from './breadcrumb';
import IssuePage from '~/components/common/issue-page';

export default {
    components: {
        PageBreadcrumb
    },
    extends: IssuePage,
    computed: {
        ...mapState('domestic', ['confirmInfo']),
        urlSuffix: () => 'domestic-flights'
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use jsx in .vue files.

Just write plain HTML

Example.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello, I am just HTML
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use the vue cli to generate a first step project. You won't have any JSX inside your code.